# How to use Scrapy and Splash to crawl LeetCode

Tags: python, scrapy, splash-screen

I am a newbie to Python and Spider. I am now trying to use Scrapy and Splash to crawl dynamic pages rendered with js, such as crawling problems from https://leetcode.com/problemset/all/.

But when I use response.xpath("//div[@class='css-1ponsav']") in https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/ , it seems not to get any information.
Similarly, in login interface https://leetcode.com/accounts/login/ , when you try to call SplashFormRequest.from_response(response,...) to log in, it will return ValueError: No  element found in <200 >.

I don't know much about the front-end. I don't know if there is anything to do with graphQL used by LeetCode. Or for other reasons?

Here is the code.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import json
import scrapy
from scrapy import Request, Selector
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
from leetcode_problems.items import ProblemItem


class TestSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['leetcode.com']

    single_problem_url = "https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/"

    def start_requests(self):
        url = self.single_problem_url
        yield SplashRequest(url=url, callback=self.single_problem_parse, args={'wait': 2})

    def single_problem_parse(self, response):
        submission_page = response.xpath("//div[@data-key='submissions']/a/@href").extract_first()
        submission_text = response.xpath("//div[@data-key='submissions']//span[@class='title__qRnJ']").extract_first()
        print("submission_text:", end=' ')
        print(submission_text) #Print Nothing
        if submission_page:
            yield SplashRequest("https://leetcode.com" + submission_page, self.empty_parse, args={'wait': 2})
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not that familiar with Splash but 98% of websites that are Javascript generated can be scraped by looking at the XHR filter under Network tab looking for POST or GET responses that generate these outputs.

In your case I can see there is one response that generate the whole page without needing any special query parameters or API keys.